# ¿Como convertir formula de medida en php mysql?

Tags: php, html

Estoy tratando de obtener la cantidad de paquetes y unidades de un paquete de un determinado articulo de un inventario. 
Por ejemplo un paquete o bulto que tiene 12 unidades supongamos que hay 3 bultos disponibles y al llegar un cliente comprando 20 unidades lo cual representarian 1 bulto (que trae 12 unidades) y 8 unidades. Si entre los 3 bultos estaban disponibles 3*12 = 36 unidades menos 20 unidades que fueron compradas quedarian 16 unidades las cuales representan 1 bulto (12 unidades) y 4 unidades. He estado usando una formula en mi codigo php aplicando una relga de 3.

En el HTML archivo pedir.html

```
<form action='recive-pedido.php' method='POST'>
    CANTIDAD DE UNIDADES: <input type='number' name='cantidad' required>
    <br>
    ARTICULO: 
    <select name='articulo' required>
      <option value=''>SELECCIONE</option>
      <option value='CAFE'>CAFE</option>
      <option value='HARINA'>HARINA</option>
      <option value='AZUCAR'>AZUCAR</option>
      <option value='ARROZ'>ARROZ</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <input type='submit' name='enviar' value='Enivar'>
</form>
```

En el archivo php recive-pedido.php

```
#---------------------------------------------------
require_once('conexion.php');
$conexion = new Conexion();
#---------------------------------------------------
$cantidad = $_POST['cantidad'];
$articulo = $_POST['articulo'];
//Cantidad por bulto
$canti_x_bult = 0; //unidades expresadas en kilogramos
$bultos_inv = 0;//Bultos disponibles
//variable para almacenar los bultos a quedar en el inventario
$bultos_a_quedar = 0;
//Selecciono la cantidad disponible en la base de datos
$sql = "SELECT * FROM inventario WHERE articulo = '$articulo'";
$query = $conexion->prepare($sql);
$query->execute(array());
if($query->rowCount() > 0){
   foreach($query->fetchAll() as $ver){
     $canti_x_bult = $ver['canti_x_bult'];
     $bultos_inv = $ver['bultos_inv '];
   }
   //Hago el calculo aqui
   $bultos_a_quedar = $cantidad/$canti_x_bult;
}


/*Aqui es donde ocurre el problema es decir nl cliente si compra 20 unidades si usando esa formula divido 20 entre 12 = 1,66 es decir yo quiero saber cuanto bultos quedarian en el inventario y con cuantas unidades */
```